# Controlled Bandwidth Performance Testing in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to compare the response times for our product application using controlled bandwidth testing by setting CPS value in Jmeter for 100MBPS, 500MBPS and 600MBPS. I performed 3 single user tests with 5 loop count each - One with 100MBPS, other with 500MBPS, and last one with 600MBPS. However, the response times are quite similar for all 3 tests with a difference of max ~200ms. Is it possible?
Scenario is like Creating a new record and saving it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible especially in the case if the bottleneck is not the bandwidth of your or your server(s) network interface and especially if your test is a "single user".

My expectation is that if you open your "test" results using [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener or something like this you will see that incoming/outgoing traffic is couple of megabytes maximum and 100 MBPS is 8 megabytes per second. As soon as your test doesn't exceed that limit (or you won't see big difference)

So make sure that:

- your server's network card bandwidth is high enough, at least 1 gigabit
- your load generator's network card bandwidth is high enough, at least 1 gigabit
- your test generates sufficient load

and in this case you will see the "differences". It would also make sense to consider measuring network card channel usage using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) or equivalent

Comment: But when I am testing same flow manually in my local machine, with ~94MBPS speed, the response times are higher as compared to what I got earlier with controlled bandwidth.